# I need a class library to create PDF files(C#)

Tags: c#, pdf-generation

I need a class lib(C#) to create PDF files. But the license must be Apache or MIT(GPL and LGPL are not allowed). And it must support asian language such as Chinese, Japanese. Who can help me? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try [PDFsharp.NET](http://www.pdfsharp.net) - note the documented limitations.

> PDFsharp is the Open Source .NET library that easily creates and processes PDF documents on the fly from any .NET language. The same drawing routines can be used to create PDF documents, draw on the screen, or send output to any printer.
>
> PDFsharp is a .NET library for processing PDF file. You create PDF pages using drawing routines known from GDI+. Almost anything that can be done with GDI+ will also work with PDFsharp. Only basic text layout is supported by PDFsharp, and page breaks are not created automatically. The same drawing routines can be used for screen, PDF, or meta files.

Comment: Yeah I have to say PDFsharp is really great. But PDFsharp does not support CJK. Their road map says they will support CJK, but............